# Limiting choices on forms field DJANGO, leaving them as they were?

Tags: python, django, forms, field, default

I have a following problem, and would appreciate some help:

the question is on the bottom :)

```
#models.py
class Task(models.Model):
    worker_on_task = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='task', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, default=User)
    #forms.py
class ChageTaskStatusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    STATUSES = (
        ('S2', 'In progress'),
        ('S3', 'Problem with'),
        ('S4', 'Finished'),
    )
    status = forms.CharField(max_length=25, widget=forms.Select(choices=STATUSES))
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['status']
```

And most important:

```
def task_details(request, pk):
    form = ChageTaskStatusForm(request.POST)
    task = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=pk)
    worker = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.user.id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            
            

    context = {
        'task': task,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'usertask/task_details.html', context)
```

I have many other fields in Task model, but I want to change only one, (status), but I get following error:

```
IntegrityError at /4/task_details/
(1048, "Column 'worker_on_task_id' cannot be null")
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/4/task_details/
Django Version: 3.2.11
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
(1048, "Column 'worker_on_task_id' cannot be null")
```

What am I missing? :/

Comment: Try this: `form.save(commit=False)` and then `task = Task.objects.filter(id=pk).update(status=form.cleaned_data['status'])`

Comment: If you want to update the existing `task` instance, you will have to pass the instance to the form, something like: `ChageTaskStatusForm(request.POST, instance=task)`. You can have a look at the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) for the explanation and an example

Comment: @BrianDestura This solved my problem! I did not come across, or just maybe I didn't read thoroughly, but that was the problem. Solved by `instance=task`. I used it before, but could not figure it out now... Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!